# Change colour of character under cursor?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, colorscheme, normal-mode

I'd like the character under my cursor to always be black in normal mode, so it contrasts with the cursor. I'm using windows terminal, which doesn't support this directly, and vim (not gvim), so guifg has no effect. Is there any way to implement this behaviour manually?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: You are most probably looking for the highlighting group `Cursor` (see [`:h hl-Cursor`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#hl-Cursor)) which defines how the character under the cursor is shown. You can use `:highlight Cursor` to see how it is defined and [`:h :highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight) to see how to change that.

Comment: @statox This seems only to work in a GUI version of Vim (e.g. GVim). In the terminal version, the cursor provided by the terminal seems to be used unchanged by Vim.